# Git pre-commit hook or option to warn when --all is used and files are already staged

Tags: git

More often than not it happens to me that I stage some partial changes with `git add -p` and then commit them with `git commit -a` out of habit. I would then have to reset and start again. Now, I'd like to see a warning when I use `git commit -a` and some files are already staged. I tried to write a pre-commit hook for this, but `--all` stages everything *before* that hook, so it cannot ever work.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not within git.  You can write a front end script, which you call git, and put that on your path in front of the "real" git; or use a shell alias `git`, that calls the "real" git, but first checks whether the sub-command is `commit`, and if so, whether there's an argument `-a`, and if so, whether there are some staged changes.  To make this super-reliable you'd have to duplicate all of git's argument parsing, but a cheap and dirty sh/bash-style alias goes like:

```
git() {
    [ x"$1" = xcommit -a x"$2" = x-a ] &&
        git_index_has_changes &&
        { echo "you have staged changes, can't use -a"; return 1; }
    command git $@
}
git_index_has_changes() {
    ! git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD --ignore-submodules
}
```

I don't really like tricky stuff like this; I find it's better to reprogram the fingers. :-)  But your mileage may vary, as they say.

Comment: Ah, I was expecting that it wouldn't be that easy. But maybe you are right and I should just "reprogram" my fingers ;-).